# How to recursively make a list of lists in SML/NJ

Tags: recursion, sml, smlnj

> I'm brand new to SML/NJ and I'm trying to make a recursive function
>   that makes a listOfLists. Ex: `listOf([1,2,3,4])` will output
>   `[[1],[2],[3],[4]]`. I've found a recursive `merge` in SML/NJ, and I'm
>   trying to use it as kind've an outline:

```
- fun merge(xs,nil) = xs
= | merge(nil,ys) = ys
= | merge(x::xs, y::ys) =
= if (x < y) then x::merge(xs, y::ys) else y::merge(x::xs,ys);

- fun listOf(xs) = xs
= | listOf(x::xs) = [x]::listOf(xs);
```

> I'm trying to use pattern match and I'm a little confused on it. I'm
>   pretty sure x is the head and then xs is the tail, but I could be
>   wrong. So what I'm trying to do is use the head of the list, make it a
>   list, and then add it to the rest of the list. But when trying to do
>   this function, I get the error:

```
stdIn:15.19-15.34 Error: operator and operand don't agree [circularity]
  operator domain: 'Z list * 'Z list list
  operand:         'Z list * 'Z list
  in expression:
    (x :: nil) :: listOf xs
```

> This error is foreign to me because I don't have really any experience
>   with sml/nj. How can I fix my listOf function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fairly close. The problem is that in pattern-matching, a pattern like `xs` (just a variable) can match *anything*. The fact that you end it with `s` doesn't mean that the pattern can only match a tail of a list. Using `s` in that way is just a programmer convention in SML.

Thus, in your definition:

```
fun listOf(xs) = xs
|   listOf(x::xs) = [x]::listOf(xs);
```

The first line tells SML to return *all* values unchanged, which is clearly not your intent. SML detects that this is inconsistent with the second line where you *are* trying to change a value after all.

You need to change that first line so that it doesn't match everything. Looking at that `merge` function as a template, you need something which matches a basis case. The natural basis case is `nil` (which can also be written as `[]`). Note the role that `nil` plays in the definition of `merge`. If you use `nil` instead of `xs` for the pattern in the first line of your function definition, your second line does exactly what you want and the function will work as intended:

```
fun listOf(nil) = nil
|   listOf(x::xs) = [x]::listOf(xs);
```

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I know stack overflow can be picky about asking another question within a question, but since it's a simple question I hope it won't matter. I'm needing to make a listOf like: `[[1],[2],[3],[4]]` into `[[1,2],[3,4]]`. How would I access the next index of the list since `x` is the first value and `xs` is the last value of a list?

Comment: Don't think of using indices at all, use pattern matching instead. Hint: `[x]::[y]::zs` is a pattern of a list with at least two elements, each of which are singleton lists.